# Как можно упростить регулярное выражение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Я написала регулярку, она работает, но выглядит некрасиво

```
^(.*\s|.*[^а-яА-ЯёЁ]|.{0})(МКУ|ИП)(\s.*|.*[^а-яА-ЯёЁ]|.{0})$
```

Задача такая: в строке надо найти соответствие `ИП` или `МКУ`, при чём так что

1. Элемент списка
2. Если перед `МКУ|ИП` есть другие русские буквы, то перед `МКУ|ИП` должен быть пробел
3. Если после `МКУ|ИП` есть другие русские буквы, то после `МКУ|ИП` должен быть пробел
4. Строка может быть простой `МКУ` или `ИП`
5. `МКУ|ИП` может стоять в начале или конце строки
6. Вокруг `МКУ|ИП` могут быть кавычки или другие не русские символы

Comment: Может, [`\b(МКУ|ИП)\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%d0%9c%d0%9a%d0%a3%7c%d0%98%d0%9f%29%5cb&i=%22!D%40%40%40%24%d0%9c%d0%9a%d0%a3%25%23%5eT%0d%0a----%d0%98%d0%9f*%28%26%28%29*%29%0d%0a%d0%9c%d0%9a+%d0%a3%d0%98%d0%9f%0d%0a%d0%9c%d0%9a%d0%a3+%d0%98%d0%98%d0%98%d0%98%d0%98%d0%9f%0d%0a%d0%9c%d0%9a%d0%a3%d0%98%d0%9f)? Или [`(?<!\S)(МКУ|ИП)(?!\S)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%28%d0%9c%d0%9a%d0%a3%7c%d0%98%d0%9f%29%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=%d0%9c%d0%9a%d0%a3+%d0%98%d0%9f%0d%0a%d0%9c%d0%9a%d0%a3+%d0%98%d0%98%d0%98%d0%98%d0%98%d0%9f%0d%0a%d0%9c%d0%9a%d0%a3%d0%98%d0%9f)?

Comment: Помогло? Какой язык программирования? В JS можно использовать `/(^|\s)(МКУ|ИП)(?!\S)/`, только код надо поправить в зависимости от того, удаляете вы или хотите получить список всех совпадений.

Comment: \b(МКУ|ИП)\b не подходит так как символы русские а \b для латинских (или я чего то не знаю =))  язык js  (?<!\S)(МКУ|ИП)(?!\S) и /(^|\s)(МКУ|ИП)(?!\S)/ подходит если не учитывать что может быть строка "Саша"ИП"Саша"

Comment: Т.е. эти 2 значения нужно найти в любой позиции, но только не между двух русских букв? [`(^|[^а-яА-ЯёЁ])(МКУ|ИП)(?![а-яА-ЯёЁ])`](https://regex101.com/r/dcHls8/1)?

Comment: ну типо в любой позиции но не в составе слова из русских букв, последнее решение думаю подходит, спасибо!) Напишите пожалуйста этот вариант в ответе к вопросу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы найти `МКУ` или `ИП` в любой позиции в строке, кроме как между двух букв русского алфавита, можно использовать

```
/(^|[^а-яА-ЯёЁ])(МКУ|ИП)(?![а-яА-ЯёЁ])/
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/dcHls8/1).

**Подробности**

- `(^|[^а-яА-ЯёЁ])` - начало строки (`^`) или (`|`) любой символ, отличный от `[^а-яА-ЯёЁ]`
- `(МКУ|ИП)` - `МКУ` или `ИП`
- `(?![а-яА-ЯёЁ])` - блок предварительного просмотра вперед, который требует отсутствия русской буквы сразу после `МКУ` или `ИП`.

Если текущая среда поддерживает стандарт ECMAScript 2018 (например, последние версии Chrome, Node.JS), можно использовать блок предварительного просмотра назад вместо захватывающей подмаски в начале выражения:

```
/(?<![а-яА-ЯёЁ])(МКУ|ИП)(?![а-яА-ЯёЁ])/
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```